# There are $n$ nails in a row fixed on a wall and $r$ rings are (all) to be placed on them.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

$Q:$ There are $n$ nails in a row fixed on a wall and $r$ rings are (all) to be placed on them. Suppose that some, none or all the rings can be placed on a nail. In how many ways can this be done if the order of the rings on a nail is ignored.

The book gave the answer $n^r$ and I want to know why is it this, why not ${n-1+r}\choose{r}$

Comment: The answer of $n^r$ is for when the rings are all distinguishable from one another.  The answer of $\binom{r+n-1}{n-1}$ or as you say $\binom{n-1+r}{r}$ (*they are equal*) is for when the rings are indistinguishable from one another.  They are both correct answers to different problems and the question statement was not explicit which problem was intended.

Comment: OK! But still won’t $n^r$ be counting ordered pairs? Like $R_1, R_2$ on $N_1$ with $R_2, R_1$ on $N_1?$

Comment: No.  All this would be is "What nail was ring1 put on? (*n options*)  What nail was ring2 put on? (*n options*) ..."  giving $n\times n\times \cdots \times n = n^r$.  If the answer to both of these first two questions was "the first nail" it does not distinguish between different orders of rings on the nail... it might have been that the first ring was closer to the wall than the second or it might have been the other way around.

Comment: Okay makes sense, Thanks! @JMoravitz

Comment: Is there a way on MSE to ask doubts rather than framing a question and asking it on main area?

Comment: By the way, in saying "the order of the rings on a nail is ignored" the question is implicitly suggesting that the rings _can_ be distinguished from each other, because if they couldn't, then it wouldn't be meaningful to talk about the order of the rings on a nail.

Comment: "Is there a way on MSE to ask doubts..." : To the best of my knowledge, no there isn't.  You have to post a question to get the question answered.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Hmmmm, yeah got it.

Answer (score 1):

As JMoravitz stated in his comment, if the rings are distinguishable, the answer would indeed be $n^r$. Here's why.

Let's start with the first ring. It can be placed on any of the $n$ nails. So $n$ ways.

There are no restrictions on the number of rings that can be placed on an individual nail. So, each ring can be placed in $n$ ways.

Multiplying them together, we have $n^r$ ways (one $n$ for each ring).